# "Every Branch Shares The Same Root" - having trouble translating "Shares"

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, motto

I'm having trouble translating "every Branch Shares The Same Root" into Latin for a school emblem. so far I have "OMNE GENERE CONSOCIARE QUOD IDEM RADIX" also this is a bit long for a school emblem patch. If there would be something shorter I could uses with fewer phrases please let me know! The name of the school is "The Global Great Growers Institute." Thank you and I appreciate your advice!

Comment: obligatory 'hodie natus est radici frater' (an infamous Multics error message)

Comment: First piece of advice: Don't use Google Translate for Latin. It is always wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My suggestion is:

> *Rami universi ex una radice.*

Literally, this means "all the branches from the same root".
There is no need for an explicit verb, especially for a motto.
There are a couple of choices here I wish to point out explicitly:

- The wording is compact so as to fit a motto.
- I used chiastic word order to highlight the branches and the root at the ends of the motto. It also puts the words *universi* and *una* next to each other for emphatic comparison.
- There are [many words for "all" in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5104/79). Out of these, *universi* means most "all together". The word itself means literally "turned into one".

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply you have been very helpful, I have a follow up question based on what you have written. What is the difference between Radice and Radix? Would one over the other change the meaning of the phrase?

Comment: @SacredSeed I'm glad to be able to help! Those are different cases (forms) of the same word. The preposition *ex* requires the ablative case. The nominative is *radix*, the ablative is *radice*, and there is a bunch of other forms as well. If you change the form, the sentence becomes ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate it as:

> Omnis ramus eiusdem radicis socius est.

And to make it shorter, you could use:

> Omnis ramus radicis socius.

That simply reads:

> Every branch is a partaker of the root.

However, to answer your question, *communicare* is a verb which means to share. It might be used as follows:

> Omnis ramus eandem radicem communicat.