# What is the difference between cunctus and totus?

Tags: synonyms

What is the difference between cunctus and totus? Dictionaries give the same meaning for both (all, whole, entirety), but in usage I see certain tendencies. For example, in ecclesiastical Latin, when speaking of the entire world, there seems to be a definite preference for `mundus cunctus`.

Comment: You might throw *omnis* and *universus* in the mix as well. I think the distinctions can get a little esoteric.

Comment: We could start with the TLL entry for *cunctus*, e.g. http://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#31452 (see DIFF., lines 53-73)

Comment: Already explained at https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5104/comparison-of-omnes-cuncti-and-universi/5105#5105